Spring Boot 3.3.2 -> 3.3.3: MockWebServerTest fails with IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format
After updating the project from Spring Boot 3.3.2 to 3.3.3 the tests which use okhttp3 MockWebServer started to fail in one specific case with:
WARN 10447 --- [mockwebserversandbox] [or-http-epoll-2] r.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect    : [1c6d7513-2, L:/127.0.0.1:45548 - R:127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:59000] The connection observed an error

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: VERSION=9HTTP/1.1
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:135) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.112.Final.jar:4.1.112.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:89) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.112.Final.jar:4.1.112.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpResponseDecoder.createMessage(HttpResponseDecoder.java:195) ~[netty-codec-http-4.1.112.Final.jar:4.1.112.Final]


I created a sample project which reproduces the problem - available here
The problem occurs when the Dispatcher class assigned to MockWebServer class returns the following response (see ControllerTest) class from repository:
return new MockResponse().setResponseCode(204).setBody("version=9");

Then the next request somehow sends HTTP version attribute with prepended string "VERSION=9", so instead of "HTTP/1.1" it is "VERSION=9HTTP/1.1"
If I change spring boot version to 3.3.2 in main pom.xml the problem doesn't occur.
In spring boot 3.3.3 it can be fixed by changing the request from
return new MockResponse().setResponseCode(204).setBody("version=9");

to
return new MockResponse().setResponseCode(204);

But I would like to understand why the problem started to appear in spring boot 3.3.3? Has the mentioned MockResponse always been wrong for some reason and the problem started to appear in version 3.3.3 or maybe the MockResponse is correct but there is a bug in Spring Boot or in any of its dependencies?
Any suggestions are very welcome.
What I've tried:

Going back to Spring Boot 3.3.2 can fix the problem but I want to be able to update to any new version that will be released
removing "setBody("version=9)"  fixes the problem in 3.3.3 by I don't know why exactly
checked HTTP status 204 description and its section "Compatibility notes" with info


Although this status code is intended for responses with no body, servers may erroneously include data after the headers ...


And not only this, PreAuthorize with variables fail, i tried to follow the migration procedure for parameter name retention, but it does not solve the issue
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#core-container

This isn't really an answer, as it says what you tried didn't work. It should have been added as a comment or an edit.
